# Empty set and the difference between subset and contains

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Why is true that the empty set is a proper subset of {x} but it is not $\in$ x?

Is this just a thing to memorize or is there some fundamental concept at play here? To me it seems like this is just a rule with a wink and a nod, as in  it has no real logic to it at this point.

Comment: Generally, nothing in mathematics (or anything else that is worthwhile) is just a rule with a wink and a nod, and no logic to it. As for the question at hand: a sack containing just a single banana certainly contains everything there is in an empty sack, but it does not contain in it an empty sack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation $a\in B$ denotes that the element $a$ is actually a member of the set $B$.

The notation $A\subseteq B$ denotes that every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$.

In your example: every element in the empty set $\{\}$ is certainly also an element of $\{x\}$... this is vacuous, because there ARE no elements in $\{\}$.

On the other hand, $\{\}$ is *not* an element of $\{x\}$; if it were, your set would look like, for instance, $\{x,\{\}\}$.  It would literally mean that the empty set was an element of the set in question... but in this case, that set contains only one element, namely $x$.

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks.